# sql 2005 fulltext catalogs inaccessible

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-catalog

Recently, and without any errors in the logs, my fulltext catalogs have stopped responding. I can't disable/delete/rename them. SSMS reports a generic error (1222) and using sql commands in the query window to remove the fulltext catalogs results in neverending executions. All the fulltext catalogs in multiple databases (same server) aren't responding. Using FREETEXT or CONTAINS times out.

what should I be checking or looking for? I'm completely out of ideas. The fulltext catalogs have been working just fine for years.

Thank you

Comment: Update: 
SELECT FullTextServiceProperty('ResourceUsage')
Causes a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what 'fixed' it. Disable fulltext index service, restart server. uninstall full text service using sql 2005 installer. Restart server. Delete all fulltext catalogs for every database. Install full text service, restart server.

All this and no indication as to the nature of the error. :/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same issue, and just disable full-text search, restart SS, re-enable full text search, re-start SS fixed it for me.